# C accessing struct pointer variable element from a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following structures, and I want be able to access elements of the StudentType:

```
typedef struct {
  int  studentID;
  char name[MAX_STR];
  char degree[MAX_STR];
} StudentType;

typedef struct {
  StudentType *elements[MAX_ARR];
  int size;
} StudentArrType;
```

My function:

```
void initStuArr(int studentID, char *name, char *degree, StudentType **stu, StudentArrType **stuArr){
```

I have tried the following both of which don't allow me to access *elements:

```
stuArr->*elements->studentID = studentID
```

and

```
stuArr->(*elements)->studentID = studentID
```

I am receiving the error: expected identifier before '*' token and '(' token when I try the 2 above. when I try `stuArr->elements->studentID = student ID`
without using the *, I get the error: request for member 'elements' in something not a structure or union.

How can I access *elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `stuArr` is a pointer to a pointer, you need to dereference it with `*` to get to the pointer. And since `elements` is an array, you need to index it to get to a `StudentType *`, which you can then use to get to `studentId`.

```
(*stuArr)->elements[i]->studentId.
```